# Django: ValidationError is stuck

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

My ValidationError seems to be stuck somewhere!
The routine clean() seems to be running as expected since I am not being forwared to `success_url`, but **the error message does not show up**.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        raise forms.ValidationError('basic error')
    class Meta:
        model = Person
```

**views.py**

```
class ContactView(generic.edit.FormView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
    template_name = 'union/contact.html'
    form_class = ContactForm    # class of union/forms.py
    success_url = '/union/VIP_confirm'
    context_object_name = 'contact'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ContactView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['count'] = countcal()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if True:
            model_id = form.save()

        person_id = model_id.pk
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse('union:VIP_save', kwargs={'person_id': person_id}))
```

**union/contact.html** template for the ContactView

```
<form action="{% url 'union:ContactView' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for field in form %}
                            {{ field.errors }}
                            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
                    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="abschicken" />
<!-- regular value submission -->
</form>
```

I followed the official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) and several other sources but to no success as to find out what the problem is or where it lies. To solve this, do you need additional infos about my app?

**EDIT:** I seem to miss something in the template, since the test error message (basic error) shows up if the template just uses the form-placeholder `{{form}}`

Using Django 1.7.1

**EDIT EDIT:**
OK. The comments pointed me to the right direction. I missed `{{form.errors}}`.

Comment: What's happening with your view syntax? Please make corrections.

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: Also, do you have {{ form.errors }} in your template already?

Comment: Is there a way for me to know this only by following the tutorial? I guess I can find out by checking the source code. At what spot in the source code could I find out about this? **Just asking generally to become better at educating myself with Django.**

Comment: Honestly, trial and error.  You're on the right track trying things out, getting stuck, and then looking for help.

Comment: Also, sometimes this stuff is [buried a little deeper in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages) so you have to go hunting for it.  Don't worry, you'll eventually learn how to use google to find the exact answers you need.